# What are helpful tricks to solve quantifiers questions in discrete mathematics?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

What are useful tricks to solve quantifiers questions? Like for example here
Let P(x,y) be the statement "x has taken y" and Q(x) be the statement "& knows Java", where the domain for x consists of all students and the domain for y consists of all Math courses. The statement "No student has taken any Math course or knows lava" is formulated by ∀x∀y(¬P(x,y) ^ ¬Q(x))

Like here why it is using and, while the question stated or
I want general tricks to help me solve those types of questions

Comment: See e.g. [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4277137/why-does-some-student-has-asked-every-faculty-member-a-question-translate-to)

Answer (score 0):

One good strategy is to divide and conquer, while following some well-known patterns.

For example, many statements involving quantifiers follow one of the following four forms:

"All of [these] are like [that]"

"Some of [these] are like [that]"

"None of [these] are like [that]" (which is equivalent to "All of [these] are not like [that]"

"Some of [these] are not like [that]"

If $P(x)$ is a formula that formalizes "x is one of [these]", and $Q(x)$ symbolizes "x is like [that]", these four general patterns respective symbolize as:

$\forall x (P(x) \to Q(x))$

$\exists x (P(x) \land Q(x))$

$\forall x (P(x) \to \neg Q(x))$

$\exists x (P(x) \land \neg Q(x))$

These statements show a nice split between what's called the 'subject term' (the things that the statement is about) and the 'predicate term' (that what we say/predicate about those things). So this gives you a natural way to break up the symbolization. For example, take your statement:

> "No student has taken any Math course or knows Java"

First, this statement is of the second general form: "None of these are like that", and thus you get:

$\forall x (P(x) \to \neg Q(x))$

What is the subject term $P(x)? What are the things that we are making a claim about?  It is clearly students.

What is the predicate term $Q(x)? What do we say about these students?  To be exact: what is it that we say is not true for these students? That they have take taken a Math course or know Java.

OK, so now we have:

$\forall x (\text{x is a student} \to \neg \text{x has taken a Math course or knows Java})$

Interestingly, the domain is already restricted to students, so we actually don't need a predicate for that, and so this collapses to:

$\forall x (\neg \text{x has taken a Math course or knows Java})$

and thus to:

$\forall x (\neg (\text{x has taken a Math course} \lor \text{x knows Java}))$

Now, to symbolize that "$x$ has taken a math course", you should recognize that this is the second of the four general forms as well, because we can rephrase this as:

"There is some math course that $x$ has taken" (we say something about a math course, and what we say about it is that $x$ has taken it)

So this symbolizes as:

$\exists y (\text{y is a math course} \land \text{x has taken y})$

OK, so using $M(y)$ for "$y$ is a math course", and $T(x,y)$ for $x$ has taken $y$, we get:

$\exists y (M(y) \land T(x,y))$

So this symbolizes "$x$ has taken a math course".

If we then use $J(x)$ for "$x$ knows Java", we can plug this all into the already indicated form of the whole statement:

$\forall x (\neg (\exists y (M(y) \land T(x,y)) \lor J(x)))$

which by DeMorgan is equivalent to:

$\forall x (\neg \forall y (M(y) \land T(x,y)) \land \neg J(x)))$

and by quantifier negation to:

$\forall x (\forall y \neg (M(y) \land T(x,y)) \land \neg J(x)))$

Another DeMorgan:

$\forall x (\forall y (\neg M(y) \lor \neg T(x,y)) \land \neg J(x)))$

And Implication:

$\forall x (\forall y (M(y) \to \neg T(x,y)) \land \neg J(x)))$

So that is almost the same as you have ... though you didn't have a predicate for something being a Math course ( which you really should) ... and of course I changed the predicate letters in some more telling letters (always a good thing to do as well if you have the freedom to do so)